# Dingo API transformer

Tags: php, laravel, dingo-api

I have below transformer which works but there is unnecessary array in the response.

```html
class NamedayTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(Nameday $nameday)
    {
        return [
            'nameday' => $nameday->name,
            'day' => $nameday->day,
            'month' => $nameday->month,
        ];
    }
}
```

This is the response

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "nameday": "František",
            "day": 4,
            "month": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

I would prefer to have simple json instead of array IN json. Could you please recommend a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you use `get()` which returns a collection. That is possible array of objects. So it's not dependent on Dingo API.

If the data you want to return is supposed to be just one object, you can try `first()`